# Flash High Scores

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, leaderboards

I have a Flash game running on a Google Sites web page right now. My main goal is to eventually convert it to an Android app. For testing and for my friends to play though, I want to store high scores on the Google Sites version.

Right now I am using SharedObjects but that is only local. What is the best way to store high scores so I can see other's scores. I've been searching for a while and I found some stuff about PHP and MySQL but I don't know a lot about that or if its possible with Google Sites.

I am not really worried about people hacking the scores, I just want something quick and simple, especially since it probably won't be used when I convert it to an Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://playtomic.com/ or http://gamersafe.com/

Both of them offer online leaderboards and are very simple to integrate with a Flash game (both require registration though, but it's free).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you need some sort of server side scripting support to be able to handle a 'true' high score table like you're talking about.  A bit of research turned up that google sites does **not** support any server side languages.

However, depending on the abilities of flash, and google docs spreadsheets, you might be able to hack something together where your game 'submits' a form to google docs, and then reads it back.  This is a completely untested idea, and if it is possible, it's almost certainly a really hacky solution, and might be more complex than simply getting a web server to handle the scores.

Alternate option: set up a web server on your local machine, and use that for the high score list.  There's other potential issues if you do this, but it would work if your game doesn't get found by something like reddit.

Answer (score 0):

I will add a vote for [mochi](http://www.mochimedia.com/developers/scores.html) and [kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/developer_center/docs/kongregate-api). They both have very simple to integrate highscore lists, and are both free.